# How can I create a HTML/JavaScript element that when I click it it shows a different element in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Basically I have these `<img/>`  elements kind of like a bunch of buttons stacked like a table. In the code, they are created through a loop (`.map()` in React.js).

I want to know the most practical and semantically-efficient way to implement a way to click a button and have it "turn over" or basically show a new element, say a `<p></p>`, in its place.

Should I have the `<img />` be wrapped in a or maybe a `<div>`? Or nothing at all?

I can think of several ways to implement the functionality I described above, such as having the `<p></p>` display 'none' originally, and when clicked display 'initial.' I implemented that in a JavaScript DOM event listener, but I am trying a new approach with React and I believe that my code was very rudimentary and inefficient.

How can I approach this 'click and flip' functionality in React.js? it "turn over" or basically show a new element, say a `<p></p>`, in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state to show image or another content. Change the state when user click the image tag. Display the content depending on the state in the render function.

```
constructor {
   this.state = {
       mode: 'image'
   }
}


render() {
const {mode} = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        {
            mode === "image" ? <img onClick={()=>{this.setState("div")}}/>:(
                <div>//content here</div>
            )             
        }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```